# Principle of uniform boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $T:[0,1]\rightarrow L(X)$ a map and for all $x\in X$ let

$f_x:[0,1] \rightarrow X, t\mapsto T(t)x \ $   be continuous.

Show that there exists a $c>0$ with $\lvert \lvert T(t)\rvert \rvert \leq c, \ t\in[0,1].$

Hint: For a fixed $x\in X$ consider $\ g_x:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,\infty), \ t\mapsto ||T(t)x||_X = ||f_x(t)||_X.$

Can one use the principle of uniform boundedness to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The family $T(t), t\in [0,1]$ is a family of continuous operators.

For every $x\in X$, the image of $f_x$ is compact since $f_x$ is continous and the image of a compact set by a continuous map is compact. We deduce that $f_x([0,1]=\{T(t)(x),t\in [0,1]\}$ is bounded since it is compact. We can apply the uniform boundedness principle to show that the family $T(t) $ is bounded.